# How to add form-control class in default django admin login form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am new in Django, I want to change class name of text-box of default djando admin login form text box.
I can change he default html template of login page but cant change class name of textbox within form input.

```
{{ form.password }}
```

Comment: You can set the attributes of the widget: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances

Comment: but how can override default login page. I cant understand.

Comment: You subclass the view/form/...

Comment: An alternative could be to make some `.css` that looks like `#idofpassword { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

use this in HTML code

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("id_password").addClass("form-control");
});
</script>
```

or:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("id_password").attr('class', "form-control");
});
</script>
```